# Multiple Futures in a Sequence in Scala

Tags: scala, future

I have two computations that happen in a Future as below:

```
val comp1 = Future { ... }
val comp2 = Future { ... }
```

I want this to run such that comp2 always runs after comp1 has completed! I know that using a for expression, I can compose these two Future's like.

```
for {
  comp1Result <- comp1
  comp2Result <- comp2
} yield { ... }
```

What could be the guarantee that comp1 is completed before comp2? I mean these are computations that happen in a different thread and there is no guarantee to the order in which this might be run. Is there a way to guarantee order without blocking?

Comment: Does the Scala Async solves this?

Comment: Well... if you want you can just put the other future in the onComplete of the first one, if that serves your purpose.

Comment: What if I have 4 of them in a chain with each Future in the chain needs the one before it to be completed?

Comment: `map` and flatMap are used for that. `future2 = future1.map( val => 2*val )` or `future2 = future1.flatMap( val => buildFuture( val ) )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala for comprehensions are syntactic sugar for combinations of flatMap and map calls on the 'container type' (Futures, in this case), so your code above equates to:

```
comp1.flatMap{ comp1Result => comp2 }
```

the computation inside the curly braces here occurs only after comp1 completes and returns a successful result (in the case of failure, the internal computation doesn't get executed).

If you define comp2 outside of the for comprehension as shown in the question, you are kicking off that computation then (you just ignore the outcome until you're inside the for comprehension), but if you define it only inside the for comprehension, then it won't be kicked off unless and until comp1 completes successfully. So, try rejigging the code as follows:

```
val comp1 = Future { ... } // or you could put this construction inside the for as well
for {
  comp1Result <- comp1
  comp2Result <- Future { ... } // Only start the computation here
  comp3Result <- Future { ... } // etc. for as many such computations as you need
} yield { ... }
```

Other alternatives are to declare comp2 as a lazy val (so it isn't actually evaluated - kicking off the computation - until it is referenced), or as a lambda (eg `val comp2 = () => Future { ... }`) and call it with the line

```
  comp2Result <- comp2()
```

inside the for comprehension.

Comment: Does the Scala Async offer me the same behavior that I need in my case?

Comment: It is possible that it might in this particular case, but I would strongly recommend avoiding use of Async (at least outside of tests) if at all possible, and becoming familiar with the above "monadic" style of computation, where you keep propagating the 'context' (here, the Future monad) as long as possible. Think of it as structuring your code like you are writing a prescription for what you want done, with the actual chain of computations only carried out at the last possible moment.

Comment: Why would you recommend against using Async other than the fact with getting familiar with monadic computation style?

Comment: Perhaps "strongly" recommend was overstating things :)  Mostly I feel it can easily lead to confusion over what code fragments are being executed when (and where) and what results are available to other bits of code. In simple cases I'm sure you can manage it well enough and it seems straight-forward, but production code rarely remains that simple in my experience. I admit I haven't worked with Async, though, so someone with greater experience working with it might be able to provide better guidance. To me, the for comprehension feels cleaner and easier to reason about.